# A Convex Function Inequality (Similar to Convex Function Definition)

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{\left(\beta x + \frac{1}{\beta x}\right)^2 + \alpha}$, where $\beta \ge 1$, $x > 0$, and $\alpha \ge 0$. Note that $f(x)$ is a convex function and is monotonically decreasing for $0 < x < 1$ and monotonically increasing for $x \ge 1$. Consider $g(x)=f(x)+ f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x \ge 1$. It can be shown that $g(x)$ is a monotonically-increasing convex function (for $x \ge 1$).

Now consider the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
\lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda) g(y) \ge g(z),
\end{equation}
where $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y \le z$, but $\frac{\lambda}{x} + \frac{1-\lambda}{y} \ge \frac{1}{z}$, and $\lambda \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) + (1-\lambda) \left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right) = z + \frac{1}{z}$ for $x,y,z \ge 1$.

I am trying to prove that the inequality holds under the given constraints. If $\alpha=0$  then the inequality can easily be proven. Also, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be used to prove that the inequality holds when the constraints are satisfied with the equality; i.e., $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y = z$. For other cases, I numerically checked whether the inequality holds or not and found that it holds for the tested numerical values.

I believe I need to use some more properties of $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ (other than convexity) to prove the assertion. Any help would be appreciated.